# eSign API Error: A requested plan item is not enabled for this account. SignInEachLocation

Tags: docusignapi

using developer sand box account, I am trying to use draw option only to sign documents. I am using Signer.SignInEachLocation property to enable it. But I am getting A requested plan item is not enabled for this account SignInEachLocation error. How to enable it for developer sandboxes.

Answer (score 0):

Please email go-live@docusign.com with your developer account number.

We would check to ensure that your account has this feature.